# Can't get SQLAlchemy func.lower to work with MySQL

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am doing some silly mistake with the syntax but cant figure out what.

I am trying to use **sqlalchemy**    `func` to compare a DB field and a variable by turning them both in lower cases, but the output comes null as if the condition isn’t satisfying.

The same thing works if I don’t use `func` and pass a static variable.

The Code:

```
question = "Hey"
q1 = QuestionsAndAnswers.query.filter(func.lower(QuestionsAndAnswers.question) == func.lower(question)).all()
q2 = QuestionsAndAnswers.query.filter(QuestionsAndAnswers.question == "Hey").all()
print "q1", q1
print "q2", q2
```

The Output:

```
q1 []
q2 [<intercom_bot.models.QuestionsAndAnswers object at 0x7f1e2c7add50>]
```

The DB:

```
+----+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
| id | question        | answer                                           | created_at |
+----+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
|  1 | Hi              | Hey, Here I am and here you are. How can I help? | NULL       |
|  2 | Hello           | Hey, Here I am and here you are. How can I help? | NULL       |
|  3 | Helo            | Hey, Here I am and here you are. How can I help? | NULL       |
|  4 | Heelo           | Hey, Here I am and here you are. How can I help? | NULL       |
|  5 | Hell            | Hey, Here I am and here you are. How can I help? | NULL       |
|  6 | Hallo           | Hey, Here I am and here you are. How can I help? | NULL       |
|  7 | Hey             | Hey, Here I am and here you are. How can I help? | NULL       |
|  8 | He              | Hey, Here I am and here you are. How can I help? | NULL       |
|  9 | Ho              | Hey, Here I am and here you are. How can I help? | NULL       |
| 10 | I need help     | Hey, Here I am and here you are. How can I help? | NULL       |
| 11 | Help            | Hey, Here I am and here you are. How can I help? | NULL       |
| 12 | can you help me | Hey, Here I am and here you are. How can I help? | NULL       |
| 13 | Greetings       | Hey, Here I am and here you are. How can I help? | NULL       |
+----+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

PS:

```
print QuestionsAndAnswers.query.filter(func.lower(QuestionsAndAnswers.question) == func.lower(question))
```

gives this:

```
 SELECT questions_and_answers.id AS questions_and_answers_id, questions_and_answers.question AS questions_and_answers_question, questions_and_answers.answer AS questions_and_answers_answer, questions_and_answers.created_at AS questions_and_answers_created_at 
FROM questions_and_answers 
WHERE lower(questions_and_answers.question) = lower(:lower_1)
```

PPS: Here's the model.

```
class QuestionsAndAnswers(Base):
    """docstring for QuestionsAndAnswers"""
    __tablename__ = 'questions_and_answers'
    id = Column(BIGINT, primary_key=True)
    question = Column(MEDIUMBLOB, nullable=False)
    answer = Column(MEDIUMBLOB, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DATETIME, nullable=True,
                        default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `==question.lower()`?

Comment: Try examining the query itself: `print(QuestionsAndAnswers.query.filter(func.lower(QuestionsAndAnswers.question) == func.lower(question)))` and see if anything strange shows up.

Comment: Also, are you using MySQL? Is `question` attribute a binary string? ["`LOWER()` (and `UPPER()`) are ineffective when applied to binary strings (`BINARY`, `VARBINARY`, `BLOB`). "](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lower). At least you're using python 2, so `"Hey"` is a byte-string and so `func.lower(question)` is ineffective (no-operation), I think.

Comment: Try this: `print db.session.query(func.lower(question)).scalar()`. Do you get `"Hey"` or `"hey"` (starting to sound like Krusty here...).

Comment: In fact it should match, if both were ineffective, as `"Hey" == "Hey"`... So check both.

Comment: @syntonym No, `==question.lower()` doesn’t make any difference.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yes I am using MySQL. and `type(question)` returns `<type 'unicode'>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114937/discussion-between-nagri-and-ilja-everila).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the MySQL functions `LOWER()` and `UPPER()` [cannot handle binary string types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) and just return the binary string unmodified.

As the column in question

```
question = Column(MEDIUMBLOB, nullable=False)
```

is a binary string type, the function application

```
func.lower(QuestionsAndAnswers.question)
```

is a no-operation and will return the binary string as is. This'll mean that the comparison will be between "Hey" and "hey" and the predicate will not match.

The proper fix would be to alter the model, table and the data to use proper text types, such as [`Unicode`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Unicode) and [`UnicodeText`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.UnicodeText), but a quick solution would be to add a cast:

```
from sqlalchemy import Unicode, cast

func.lower(cast(QuestionsAndAnswers.question, Unicode))
```